# how to track number of visitors visiting the magento site using "Google analytics" or by any other solution

Tags: google-analytics, google-api

I want to know how many visitors are visiting the Magento site.

I found  Google API here :

> System > configuration > Sales > Google API

What next do I have to do? please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Track traffic with Google Analytics

With the help of Google Analytics, you can track and measure traffic to your extension's or app's details page in the Chrome Web Store. For more details on using Google Analytics, see the Getting Started Guide in the Google Analytics Help Center.

#### Set up Google Analytics for your item's details page

1. Sign in to Google Analytics at http://www.google.com/analytics.
2. Create a new account for your item's details page. On the Overview page, click the "My Analytics Accounts" menu on the top-right corner of the page and select **Create New Account**.
   Although it's possible to simply create a new profile within an existing account, we recommend creating a new account so that the data for your details page isn't impacted by the data from your other websites.
3. Once your account is created, click its name on the Overview page. Find its Google Analytics Profile ID next to the URL for your details page. The ID looks something like this: UA-123123-1
4. Sign in to the Web Store's Developer Dashboard.
5. Find the item you'd like to track and click **Edit**.
6. On the following page, find the "Google Analytics ID" field and paste your Profile ID into this field.
7. Click **Publish changes**.

Once you save your changes, it'll take up to 24 hours for data to appear in your Analytics account. If you're unable to see any data, even after 24 hours, see troubleshooting information from the Google Analytics Help Center.

#### Access Google Analytics reports

1. Sign in to Google Analytics at http://www.google.com/analytics.
2. On the Overview page, click the account you created for your details page.
3. If you have multiple profiles in this account, click **View report** next to the appropriate profile.

For more information about the types of reports available in Google Analytics, please visit the Google Analytics Help Center.

```
<script>(function(){var requestId='default';hcfeComponents[requestId].push(['hcfe','content.Content','.content-container--answer']);})();</script>
```

Comment: Can i add this in wordpress website ? If yes then how can i do this ?

Comment: you can add this any site

Comment: just follow the steps which mention above

Comment: Hi @Keyul,

Thanks a lot for reply.

I did't found 2nd step : "On the Overview page, click the account you created for your details page." under "Access Google Analytics reports".

butbelow "overview page",

I can see this list =>

1)Demographics

2)Interests

3)Geo

4)Behaviour

5)Technology

where to see the account i created?

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/188739?hl=en

Comment: hi, i think i found something. i will let you know soon....

Comment: hi, Can i get information after one day or right now after creating account and put account number in admin panel.

Comment: in admin panel i don't think so you have attach in header.phtml file

Comment: yes, i did't attached any code in admin panel or in cpanel. I just put the account number UA-5**242009-1 in admin panel. what else i have to do? Is i have to add the above code in header.phtml ?

Comment: hi, i found this : http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_google_analytics.htm i thought just adding an account number is enough.

Comment: try this :)..........

Comment: is it require 24 hours to show website visitors?

Comment: may It will take time to authenticate user

Comment: thanks, i will let you know soon about what wrong i did....

Comment: hi ,

you are fantastic keyul....

It's worked. now i am getting some information about visitors.

also as i am using cpanel, i am getting  information in "awstats" also.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @KeyulShah this questions has reached 2500 views, its all because of your answer, thanks a lot....

Answer (score 2):

Yes obviously Google Analytic is one of the best analytic tools present by Google. There are too many features that you can use like visitors location, page impression, clicks rate, bounce rate, most visited page etc. Try it yourself, you will find the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using cpanel,

1) login to cpanel

2) see logs

3) Click on "awstats".

You will get everything....