# Order Details are not displaying in admin Panel of magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, sales-order

[image]
The Order Menu Displays a Blank white screen. I can't see any order detail. please tell me suitable solution. Thanks.

Comment: Anything in var/log/system.log?

Comment: first turn on your display error so that it will display where the error is

Comment: var/log/system.log has a size of about 159 mb

Comment: from where i can turn on display error

Comment: in root index.php file ---  ini_set('display_errors', 1); remove #

Comment: where can i see all the errors...?

Comment: remove cache and refresh the same order grid page...and please share me the error what you see

Comment: i am not seeing any error on that page after turn on error display and cache remove.it shows only blank white page

Comment: i will show for sure...if not delete you log and refresh the page so that we can see something in the log

Comment: is there any other solution..?

Comment: definitely if you display errors in index.php you will get error..i think you are missing something.. please check at your end properly

Comment: i have checked properly.. nothing wrong

Comment: no without knowing the error we cant do anythig

Comment: if you are using any custom extensions , try disabling that extension

Comment: i am not using using any extension

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly a PHP issue either caused by an extension, modification or incompatible PHP version. I would comment but don't have reputation so I am answering instead.

In the browser look at the html source code - this can indicate where the page stops rendering exactly to help pinpoint the issue.

Check the error logs for the webserver you are using (apache / nginx for example)
Check the error logs for PHP and PHP-FPM(if using).

Check the version of PHP you are using is compatible with the version of magento you are using - for example PHP 7 will cause this issue.

Try disabling any extensions one by one to test. Do this by changing the xml file for the module in /app/etc/modules/  to be set to false instead of true, clear cache if on afterwards.