# Magento Search option shows irrelevant suggestions dropdown list

Tags: magento-1.9, search

When i search a particular products the search bar shows some irrelevant suggestion in a drop down as you can see in image.It shows that products categories which doesn't exist in my store. i don't want these suggestion drop down list. Please tell me a solution to remove this dropdown list. Thanks  [image]

Comment: are you using any extension for auto search?

Comment: no... i m not using any extension

Comment: suggestion displayed are not the categories, this are search terms which are used to search with count (how many times customers have searched for that terms)

Comment: is there any solution to remove these terms

Comment: you want to clear them or don't want to display in suggestion?

Comment: i don't want to display them in suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as per your response in comment-
You can manage Search terms in admin from -

> Catalog -> Search terms

Or if you don't want to display search term suggestion , you can disable it from admin at below path-

1. Go to **System -> Configuration**
2. Select **catalog** beneath Catalog tab from left navigation tab
3. Now select **Catalog Search**
4. And set  **Show Autocomplete Results Count** to **NO**

**Update :** To remove search suggestion you have to change in below file-

> /your_magento/app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml

if this file is not there in your theme , then copy it from `base/default` or `rwd/default` theme to the given path

then in `form.mini.phtml` file comment/delete this code

```
<div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete"></div>
```

and this script code

```
searchForm.initAutocomplete('<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getSuggestUrl() ?>', 'search_autocomplete');
```

Comment: there is a problem, i have done but dropdown list  still exist, only count no. removed, how we can remove these dropdown list item also

Comment: try this answer to remove them  -https://stackoverflow.com/a/8688427/4349218

Comment: actually i am new in magento, i have only little bit knowledge of codes.. is there any other way to remove or can you help me to find out the file with proper steps

Comment: do you have access to the code?

Comment: right now, i have no access of codes... any there any other way from where we can solve it from admin panel

Comment: sorry there is no option to remove them from admin, you have to make changes in code to remove

Comment: ok, can i try it on local first.. because there is also same problem

Comment: i have updated my answer with steps, you can try them and let me know if you need any further help

Comment: can i ask one more question..??

Comment: yes , feel free to ask :)

Comment: i didn't get answer of this question.. can you please check it   https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/189298/order-details-are-not-displaying-in-admin-panel-of-magento-1-9

Comment: Thanks, your solution solved my problem, i tried it on my local, no suggestion is coming now, will try it on my site, thank you so much

Comment: now please try to solve my second question for which i had given you the link.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

when you start typing something. ajax call is sent with your keywords, and your submit button is set to disabaled, when ajax response is recived, the submit button disabaility is removed.